# Selenium: Scrolling down until the 'style' of an element changes

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a review page like [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/105700/reviews/?p=1&browsefilter=mostrecent).

This has relatively few reviews, but there are others that have many more which requires a lot more scrolling.

I noticed that when the page is not at the very bottom, the element looks like this:

```
div class="apphub_NoMoreContent" id="NoMoreContent" style="display: none"
```

However, when the page is scrolled to the bottom it changes like this:

```
div class="apphub_NoMoreContent" id="NoMoreContent" style="opacity: 1;"
```

where the style changes its value.

How would I be able to scroll until the style of the element changes?

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: I first started with using screen heights but that broke for long pages, and now haven't had much success since

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this code to scroll page down until no more content to load:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/app/105700/reviews/?p=1&browsefilter=mostrecent'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

while True:
    try:
        div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="NoMoreContent" and @style="display: none"]')
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.END)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="GetMoreContentBtn" and @style=""]').click()
        except:
            pass
    except:
        break
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly. I'll have to do some search to understand the code... :)

Comment: I just found one problem, which is that while scrolling, randomly a "load more" button appears. The element is ```div class="apphub_GetMoreContent" id="GetMoreContentBtn" style="display: none;"```. Any way to click these and continue scrolling when they appear?

Comment: @user888905050219 do you mean that either `"NoMoreContent"` OR `"GetMoreContentBtn" ` might appear at the bottom of page? Can you share example of page where `"GetMoreContentBtn" ` might be present?

Comment: So for a page like this (https://steamcommunity.com/app/360430/reviews/?p=1&browsefilter=mostrecent&filterLanguage=english) at some point a "See More Content" button at the bottom of the page becomes visible. I noticed that the element is as how I described above when there is no button, but it changes to ```div class="apphub_GetMoreContent" id="GetMoreContentBtn" style=""``` when the button appears.

Comment: @user888905050219 try now

Comment: @user888905050219 Are you sure? I've been tested couple times with provided link and it scrolled page within ~5 minutes until "No more content" label... Can you pls try again?

Comment: Sorry, I think I had a syntax error. The code is working, thanks. Just that the website is odd that it won't load all of the reviews :( Nothing to do with the code though. Appreciate your help a tons!